# How do I perform GraphQL Query onClick in React with Apollo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to filter particular **Eateries** based on `foodType` which is passed as a *string* e.g.("Chicken", "Pizza" etc).

I want to be able to do it `onClick` in my **React component**.

I've tried wrapping in an `<ApolloPriver>` wrapper to do a query but not had much luck.

`FoodType.tsx`

```
export const FoodTypes: React.SFC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="food-types">
      <ul className="food-type-list">
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={async () => {
                const { data } = await client.query({
                  query: FOODTYPE_QUERY,
                  variables: { foodType: "Pizza" }
                })}}>Pizza</li>
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={}>Chicken</li>
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={}>Indian</li>
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={}>Chinese</li>
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={}>English</li>
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={}>Fish & Chips</li>
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={}>Kebab</li>
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={}>Curry</li>
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={}>Caribbean</li>
      </ul>
)}
```

The GQL query I want to pass

```
const FOODTYPE_QUERY = gql`
  query foodTypeQuery($foodType: String!) {
    getFoodType(foodType: $foodType) {
      id
      name
      address
      foodType
    }
  }
`;
```

How I'm currently showing all the eateries in `FoodTypes.tsx`. This is where I want the results to go `onClick` of the buttons above.

```
<div className={"EateryWrapper"}>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Query query={EATERY_QUERY}>
            {({ loading, data }: any) => {
              if (loading) return "Loading...";
              const { eateries } = data;
              return eateries.map((eatery: any) => (
                <EateryItem
                  key={eatery.id}
                  id={eatery.id}
                  name={eatery.name}
                  address={eatery.address}
                  foodType={eatery.foodType}
                />
              ));
            }}
          </Query>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </div>
```

The whole `FoodTypes.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import "./FoodTypes.scss";
import { ApolloProvider, Query } from "react-apollo";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

import { client } from "../..";
import { EateryItem } from "../Eatery/EateryItem";

const EATERY_QUERY = gql`
  {
    eateries {
      id
      name
      address
      foodType
    }
  }
`;

const FOODTYPE_QUERY = gql`
  query foodTypeQuery($foodType: String!) {
    getFoodType(foodType: $foodType) {
      id
      name
      address
      foodType
    }
  }
`;

export const FoodTypes: React.SFC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="food-types">
      <ul className="food-type-list">
        <li className="food-type-item" onClick={async () => {
          const { data } = await client.query({
            query: FOODTYPE_QUERY,
            variables: { foodType: "Pizza" }
          })
          console.log(data)}
        }>Pizza</li>
        <li className="food-type-item">Chicken</li>
        <li className="food-type-item">Indian</li>
        <li className="food-type-item">Chinese</li>
        <li className="food-type-item">English</li>
        <li className="food-type-item">Fish & Chips</li>
        <li className="food-type-item">Kebab</li>
        <li className="food-type-item">Curry</li>
        <li className="food-type-item">Caribbean</li>
      </ul>
      <div className={"EateryWrapper"}>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Query query={EATERY_QUERY}>
            {({ loading, data }: any) => {
              if (loading) return "Loading...";
              const { eateries } = data;
              return eateries.map((eatery: any) => (
                <EateryItem
                  key={eatery.id}
                  id={eatery.id}
                  name={eatery.name}
                  address={eatery.address}
                  foodType={eatery.foodType}
                />
              ));
            }}
          </Query>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FoodTypes;
```

**Updated `FoodTypes.tsx`**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import "./FoodTypes.scss";
import { ApolloProvider, Query } from "react-apollo";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

import { client } from "../..";
import { EateryItem } from "../Eatery/EateryItem";

const EATERY_QUERY = gql`
  {
    eateries {
      id
      name
      address
      foodType
    }
  }
`;

const FOODTYPE_QUERY = gql`
  query foodTypeQuery($foodType: String!) {
    getFoodType(foodType: $foodType) {
      id
      name
      address
      foodType
    }
  }
`;

type foodTypeFilterProps = {
  foodTypeName: String
}

export const FoodTypes: React.SFC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="food-types">
      <ul className="food-type-list">
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'Italian'}/>
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'Pizza'}/>
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'Chicken'}/>
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'Indian'}/>
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'Chinese'}/>
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'English'}/>
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'Fish & Chips'}/>
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'Kebab'}/>
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'Curry'}/>
        <FoodTypeFilter foodTypeName={'Caribbean'}/>
      </ul>
      <div className={"EateryWrapper"}>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Query query={EATERY_QUERY}>
            {({ loading, data }: any) => {
              if (loading) return "Loading...";
              const { eateries } = data;
              return eateries.map((eatery: any) => (
                <EateryItem
                  key={eatery.id}
                  id={eatery.id}
                  name={eatery.name}
                  address={eatery.address}
                  foodType={eatery.foodType}
                />
                ));
            }}
          </Query>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const FoodTypeFilter: React.FunctionComponent<foodTypeFilterProps> = props => {
  const [foodType, setFoodType] = useState(props.foodTypeName);
  return(
    <li className="food-type-item" onClick={async () => {
      const { data } = await client.query({
        query: FOODTYPE_QUERY,
        variables: { foodType: props.foodTypeName }
      })
      setFoodType(foodType);
      }}>{foodType}
      </li>
  )
}

export default FoodTypes;
```

What would the best approach be to get the above elements to use the GQL query above onClick?

Comment: What does your onClick function currently look like?  What have you tried?

Comment: Hey @Jim I've update the above example with what I've tried so far with the onClick :)

Comment: Is there any console error or any network request is being sent?

Comment: So with your onClick on `pizza`, the query should fire off and assign the result to `data`.  What are you looking to do with the result (`data`)?

Comment: Thanks @Jim I'm actually returning the correct array with the right information from GQL but I wanted to now show the data where I'm currently showing all of the `eateries`.

Updated the original question to show where I wanted the data show :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend you change your `FoodTypes` component to a React component so that you are able to store the data returned from your graphql query in `state`

```
export class classFoodTypes extends React.Component
```

Now, in your `classFoodTypes` component, you can call `setState` after fetching your data:

```
<li className="food-type-item" onClick={async () => {
                const { data } = await client.query({
                  query: FOODTYPE_QUERY,
                  variables: { foodType: "Pizza" }
                })}
                this.setState({eateries: data})}>Pizza</li>
```

From there, you can display your data from `state`:

```
            <EateryItem
              key={this.state.eateries.id}
              id={this.state.eateries.id}
              name={this.state.eateries.name}
              address={this.state.eateries.address}
              foodType={this.state.eateries.foodType}
            />
```

I'm not going to finish implementing the rest of your component so you can practice the implementation, but this pattern should help lead you in the right direction.   Let me know if you get stuck along the way.

Comment: That's awesome @Jim that almost got me there. I had to use a hook instead of a class as I'm using hooks as my main component. Not sure if I could extend it like you mentioned?

Though the real issue is now accessing the state from the `useState()` hook in the new `FoodTypeFilter` hook I added at the bottom.

I want to pass it into the `EateryItem` component to be mapped over to show the current set of Eateries.